# How can I make jmeter exlude url using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, jmeter

So I want to exclude all the responses from:

```
/javax.faces.resource/
```

for example:

```
/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.html
```

The regerx I am trying is:

```
[/javax.faces.resource/*]
```

But the responses are still captured.

What is it I that I am doing wrong?

Comment: try this `[/javax.faces.resource/.*]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [JMeter's Superpower: The HTTP Proxy Server](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-superpower-http-proxy-server) guide you need to escape dot characters as

```
(/javax\.faces\.resource/*)
```